How can I import newer versions of pre-defined SCDF starter apps?
I'm working on evaluating Spring Cloud Data Flow, and want to get a demonstration working with the out of the box apps (Kafka on Kubernetes). I'm having trouble getting things working, but before I spent too much time debugging, I wanted to make sure I had the latest version of things. I used the option to import application starters from dataflow.spring.io, and it imported a bunch of applications, but they seem to be very out of date.
All of the applications are at version 3.2.1, but I can find 5.0.0 versions of most of them at Dockerhub. For example: https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloudstream/log-sink-kafka/tags. The 3.2.1 tag is from over two years ago.
Does anyone know why the old versions are being imported? Is there a catalog somewhere on dataflow.spring.io that is just not being updated? How can I update these to newer versions?

There are 3 release train version to choose from:
2021.1.2, 2022.0.0 and 2024.0.0 which corresponds to stream apps 3.2.1, 4.0.0 and 5.0.0
You can use Add Application in the dashboard and select Import application coordinates from an HTTP URI location and provide the <URI> as described below.
OR
You can perform at REST POST to <scdf-address>:9393/apps?uri=<URI>
Where <URI> is:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/stream-applications-descriptor/${RELEASE_TRAIN}/stream-applications-descriptor-${RELEASE_TRAIN}.stream-apps-${BROKER}-${TYPE}

RELEASE_TRAIN should be one of 2021.1.2, 2022.0.0, 2024.0.0
BROKER should be one of kafka or rabbit
TYPE should be one of docker or maven

